# pass a function of an object to another std::function of another class

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

What is the right way to pass a member function of one class to an `std::function` of another class?

For example, the `Bar` below wants to store one function of a `Foo` object.

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int x) : data(x) {}
  bool isEven(int y) { return (data + y) & 0x01; }
  int data;
};

class Bar {
public:
  std::function<bool(int)> testFunction;
};


int main() {
  Foo foo1(1);
  Bar bar;
  bar.testFunction = std::bind(&Foo::isEven, &foo1);
  if (bar.testFunction(3)) {
    std::cout << "is even" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::function<bool(int)>' and 'std::_Bind_helper<false, bool (Foo::*)(int), Foo*>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (Foo::*)(int)>(Foo*)>}')**
```

Answer (score 4):

`Foo::isEven` takes an argument which you'll be passing later, so you need to add a placeholder to indicate that unbound argument.

```
bar.testFunction = std::bind(&Foo::isEven, &foo1, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Or just use a lambda instead of `bind`

```
bar.testFunction = [&foo1](int x) { return foo1.isEven(x); };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda:

```
bar.testFunction = [&foo1](int x){ return foo1.isEven(x); };
```